# Combining multiple update queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a master table from multiple auxilliary tables in Access. I was hoping to use multiple SQL statements within the confines of one query to do this. See the multiple statements below. Is there a way to write this to update both fields in the master table and use language to connect both statements within the same query? I am hoping that I don't have to create 60 update queries to do this.

```
UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Input table] 
SET [Master Output Table].[Field 1] = [Input table]![Field 1]
WHERE ((([Input table]![Field 1])="AAAA") AND (([Master Output Table]![Field 1])="BBBB"));

UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Input table] 
SET [Master Output Table].[Field 1] = [Input table]![Field 1]
WHERE ((([Input table]![Field 1])="CCCC") AND (([Master Output Table]![Field 1])="DDDD"));
```

Comment: When I use OR, I get the following:

Answer (score 1):

You can also create stored procedure and just pass 2 inputs. Then you need to call stored procedure 60 times. You can stored procedure as follows

```
Create Procedure UpdateTable
(
      @field1 VARCHAR(200),
      @field2 VARCHAR(200)

)
As
Begin
   UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Input table] 
   SET [Master Output Table].[Field 1] = [Input table]![Field 1]
   WHERE ((([Input table]![Field 1])= @field1 ) AND (([Master Output Table]![Field 1])= @field2));

End
```

Then call it like `Execute UpdateTable 'AAA','BBB'`

Answer (score 0):

Since everything else seems to be the same you should be able to just OR your here clauses:

```
UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Input table] 
SET [Master Output Table].[Field 1] = [Input table]![Field 1]
WHERE ((([Input table]![Field 1])="AAAA") AND (([Master Output Table]![Field 1])="BBBB"))
  OR
      ((([Input table]![Field 1])="CCCC") AND (([Master Output Table]![Field 1])="DDDD"))
```

Comment: This seems like the best option, but when I use or, I get a syntax error. Am I doing something wrong below? UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Augusta Input table] SET [Master Output Table].[Area Change Ar Transfer From] = [Augusta Input table]![Amount 5628]
WHERE ((([Augusta Input table]![Transaction Type 5628])="Area Change Ar Transfer From") AND (([Master Output Table]![Transaction Type])="Amount 5628"))
OR 
UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Augusta Input table] SET [Master Output Table].[Area Change Ar Transfer From] = [Augusta Input table]![Tax Amount 5628]
WHERE ...

Comment: Yes, you are not using the UPDATE command I posted.  You are repeating the UPDATE after the OR.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is that I need a new set each time. Let me try this, and I think it will work.

Comment: I received a syntax error again: UPDATE [Master Output Table], [Augusta Input table] 
SET [Master Output Table].[Area Change Ar Transfer From] = [Augusta Input table]![Amount 5628]
WHERE ((([Augusta Input table]![Transaction Type 5628])="Area Change Ar Transfer From") AND (([Master Output Table]![Transaction Type])="Amount 5628"))
OR
SET [Master Output Table].[Area Change Ar Transfer From] = [Augusta Input table]![Tax Amount 5628]
WHERE ((([Augusta Input table]![Transaction Type 5628])="Area Change Ar Transfer From") AND (([Master Output Table]![Transaction Type])="Tax Amount 5628"));

Comment: Can you help me to understand why this syntax error occurs? Is it because I have 2 SET statements?